# My database show nothing in my listview

Tags: java, android, database

In my project I have database and I want to fill data from database into my listview. But It shows nothing without any errors.
I open the database easily and get data from it and set to my arraylist and finally I put in into my listview.
where is the problem?
I am new with android 
here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private ListView listView;
  public static SqliteHelper database;
  private ArrayList<ItemJomle> arrayDatas;
  private ArrayAdapter adapter;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    arrayDatas = new ArrayList<>();
    database = new SqliteHelper(this);
    try {
        database.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstcontent);
    updateListViewData();
  }
  public void updateListViewData() {
    database.open();
    arrayDatas = database.getDataListView();
    adapter = new AdapterData(arrayDatas);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    database.close();
  }
  public static void updateFav(int id,String value){
    database.open();
    database.updateDatabase(id,value);
    database.close();
  }
}
```

And here is my code:

```
   public ArrayList<ItemJomle> getDataListView() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TBL_NAME ;

      arrayListViwedatas.clear();
      Cursor cu = Mydb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
      if(cu!=null){
      cu.moveToFirst();

      if(cu.moveToFirst()){
      while (cu.isAfterLast() == false) {
          ItemJomle item = new ItemJomle();
          item.id =  cu.getInt(cu.getColumnIndex("id"));
          item.subject =  cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("subject"));
          item.text =  cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("text"));
          item.nubmer = cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("number"));
          item.fav =  cu.getString(cu.getColumnIndex("fav"));
          arrayListViwedatas.add(item);
          cu.moveToNext();
      }
      cu.close();
      }
      }
    return arrayListViwedatas;
}

and my layout:

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ListView
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/lstcontent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:divider="@null"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <com.vizitsaz.ClickBanner_CLickYab_Holder
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can check your `adapter` with dump data, if it 's ok,  you can check your data from database.

Comment: Can you post the code of: getDataListView() , R.layout.activity_main ?Thanks

Comment: Yes I edit my question and put these

Comment: check your database is no empty

Comment: Where is the main tag of your layout? Is it a RelativeLayout?

Comment: @ValentinoS.no it is linearlayout